# How to create request/response interceptor in next 13+

Tags: next.js

I'm trying to create and apply request and response interceptor to native fetch in next13+ that supports SSR and CSR

Problem is that on SSR there is no window and on client components there is no provider that will be using in the ssr part. That means it should have at least 2 api clients, one for server and one for client.

Any idea how to apply request/response interceptor in next@13+ using native fetch?

So far i have created something like this:

```
import { getSession } from 'next-auth/react';

export * from './auth';
export * from './movies';

export const fetchApi = async (url: RequestInfo | URL, data?: any) => {
  const session = await getSession();

  const init = data
    ? {
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Authorization: `Bearer ${session?.user.accessToken}`
        }
      }
    : undefined;

  const response = await fetch(url, { ...init });

  if (!response.ok) {
    if (response.status === 401) {
      throw new Error('Unauthorized');
    }

    throw new Error('Request Failed');
  }

  return response.json();
};
```

but i'm not sure if this is the right direction